# My sticky header does not cover the viewport width

Tags: css

Please I have created a sticky header and every thing goes well except that this header does not cover all the viewport width and skips a little space at the top of the page.
I used "margin: 0" but in vain.
Thanks!!

```
<body>
<header> /*nav bar*/
</header>
<div>
/*Some content*/
</div>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
```

```
body{
display: flex;
flex-diection: column;
}

header{
position: sticky;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the body element by default has a margin of 8px. You need to add `body{margin:0}` to your css

Comment: It works with body{margin: 0}. Thanks very much..you saved me